# Почему не запускается программа записанная из массива байтов?

Tags: c++, c, файлы, потоки-данных

я из 16-ричного редактора беру байты и записываю их в массив :

```
unsigned char DllData[11264] = {
0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,...}
```

потом записываю в exe файл:

```
std::fstream DllData_s("test.exe", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(DllData); i++)
{
    DllData_s << DllData[i];
}
DllData_s.close();
```

И пытаюсь его запустить,но он не запускается и показывает что невозможно запустить это приложение на вашем пк.

Comment: Сравнивали полученные файлы?

Comment: Вы хотите сдлеать cp для испольняемого файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы компилятор не вставлял лишние символы надо текстовый вывод переключить на двоичный примерно так:

```
std::fstream DllData_s("test.exe", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);
```

Ну а вывод файла лучше сделать через fstream.write(char *ptr, int size) примерно так:

```
DllData_s.write(&DllData[0], sizeof(DllData));
```

Но если вы динамическую библиотеку пытаетесь запустит, как исполнимый файл - из этого толку не будет. Её надо подключать к приложению, а это отдельная история.

Answer (score 2):

Ну и что вы хотите?

1. Вы пишете в текстовый файл, так что, например, `0x0A` превратится в два байта - `0x0A 0x0D`.
2. Но это не так важно, потому что все равно вы пишете с использованием оператора `<<`, так что в файле будут просто текстом записанные числа.
3. По названию судя, вы берете DLL и пытаетесь переписать ее в EXE. Мелочь по сравнению с 1 и 2, но тоже неприятно...

Вы бы хоть заглянули после записи внутрь файла, что у вас получилось. Или сравнить размеры исходного файла и получившегося.

Comment: ну они +- одинаковые,с небольшими отличиями

Comment: поясните по первому пункту,почему превратится в 2 байта

Comment: Но с отличиями же! Потому что текстовый формат в Windows (а DLL уже говорит об этом :)) предусматривает перевод строки `\n` в файле как два символа - `\r\n`, и в этом, по сути, и состоит различие текстового файла от бинарного - обработка конца строки при чтении и записи.

Comment: я просто названия забыл поменять,но там не дллка

Comment: а как тогда правильно записывать бинарник?

Comment: `ostream.write((char*)DllData, sizeof(DllData));` - только файл открыть с флагом `ios.binary`. Но, по-моему, вы все равно "хотите странного" - почему именно так? Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: я хочу шифровать exe ключом который будет получаться с сервера и потом его расшифровывать

Comment: Просто два вопроса - зачем держать его в памяти, а не в отдельном файле на диске? Ну и - получив его разово в открытом виде, дальше взломщику можно этот exe забирать и распространять :) Может, лучше предусмотреть какую-то зашифрованную функциональность в самом exe?